# Is it possible to create bookmarks on certain frames?

Tags: avisynth

Is it possible to create multiple bookmarks on the timeline that represent specific frames? Let's say i want to open an .avs file and it will have several "bookmarks" on the timeline representing frames that are of interest.

Does this thing exist in AviSynth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open an .avs file in what?

If you use [AvsPmod](http://avspmod.github.io/), you can bookmark frames and jump between them quickly. You can also generate chapter files from bookmarks that you can then use in an actual encode (when muxed in a container like mp4 or mkv).